# SOLR 8.0 NoClassDefFoundError when change schema and index MSOffice and PDF files

Tags: java, solr, lucene, nosql, noclassdeffounderror

After a schema change, just added a new field in a document and indexing documents throws **NoClassDefFoundError** practically for every document MS office or PDF that worked before schema change. This error comes out as:

```
"ERROR d.t.d.d.b.d.SolrRequestExecutor - Failed to index file
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html."
```

with  `"Error 500 Server Error".`

- Linux Ubuntu 18.04
- Solr 8.0.0
- Java Oracle 1.8.

This happens only at our project version release :)

already tried:

- reload core
- reboot server
- delete and re-index all

Server has enough disk space. Cpu and memory still has reserves during indexing.

Maybe there are some temporary junk files left in "data" folder, or elsewhere. Or maybe the core gets corrupted after changing schema but it should get cleaned when reloaded.

```
2019-11-08 20:05:41 ERROR d.t.d.d.b.d.SolrRequestExecutor - Failed to index file
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/document/update/extract. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
        at org.apache.tika.parser.image.ImageParser.parse(ImageParser.java:177)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.DelegatingParser.parse(DelegatingParser.java:72)
        at org.apache.tika.extractor.ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.parseEmbedded(ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.java:102)
        at org.apache.tika.extractor.EmbeddedDocumentUtil.parseEmbedded(EmbeddedDocumentUtil.java:220)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.AbstractPOIFSExtractor.handleEmbeddedResource(AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java:124)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.AbstractPOIFSExtractor.handleEmbeddedResource(AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java:100)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handlePictureCharacterRun(WordExtractor.java:640)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleParagraph(WordExtractor.java:367)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleHeaderFooter(WordExtractor.java:259)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:182)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:175)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:131)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:228)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2559)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:711)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:394)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
</pre>

</body>
</html>

        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:607)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.dao.SolrRequestExecutor.doSolrUpdateRequest(SolrRequestExecutor.java:42)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.dao.SolrRequestExecutor.indexAuditFile(SolrRequestExecutor.java:35)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.business.handler.WordIndexingHandler.createAuditedFile(WordIndexingHandler.java:31)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.business.handler.DocumentIndexingHandler.handleAuditedFile(DocumentIndexingHandler.java:52)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.business.handler.DocumentIndexingHandler.receiveAuditedFile(DocumentIndexingHandler.java:36)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.DepDocumentBaseApplication.runSvnIndexing(DepDocumentBaseApplication.java:65)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.DepDocumentBaseApplication.scheduledRun(DepDocumentBaseApplication.java:50)
        at de.tsystems.dep.document.base.DepDocumentBaseApplication.main(DepDocumentBaseApplication.java:42)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```